# Normalization factor of truncated multivariate normal distributions (Normalization factor from samples)

Tags: probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, truncated-normal-distribution

I would like to evaluate an expectation of the form $\int p(x) \;\mathbb{1}_\left(Bx \leq 0\right) dx$, where p(x) is a multivariate normal distribution. I.e. the probability of a linear constraint being fulfilled for random variables distributed by a Gaussian.

It seems that this expectation would be the normalization factor of a truncated multivariate normal but while there are a couple of MCMC based approaches to sampling from truncated multivariate normal distributions, they do not represent the normalization factor explicitly. Is there a tractable way to calculate or approximate this expectation?

Comment: To clarify, is $x$ a vector, $B$ a matrix, and the inequality is component-wise?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: The question is quite vague: do you include importance sampling in this range of solution? do you want to restrict the estimates to those built on a truncated simulation over the set $Bx\le 0$? Is the constraint rare enough to prevent using $p(\cdot)$ for simulation?

Comment: Sorry, yes the constraint is too rare to just sample from the multivariate normal distribution. Also the dimensionality of x and Bx is somewhere between $10^2$ and $10^3$ which prohibits numerical integration. The estimate doesn't need to rely on those samplers as long as it is tractable. Importance sampling might work but I don't know which proposal distribution would do the trick here and has importance weights that are easier to compute.

Comment: If the constraint is rare, what about a uniform distribution over the set $Bx\le 0$ assuming the set is bounded.

Comment: Assuming I can use a uniform distribution over a truncated hypersphere or hypercube, I would still need to calculate the volume of the sphere/cube under that constraint to calculate the importance weights. I am not aware of an easy way to do this although my knowledge of geometry is limited.